# Access of the other drives in dual-boot system

Tags: dual-boot

I was using Scientific Linux in my PC . Then I installed Ubuntu alongside with SL . Now both OS are installed in my PC . But the problem is I cant access any other drive from my UBUNTU apart from HOME. How can I access all the drives from UBUNTU?

Comment: @rinzwind I just checked the title. i m sorry for that discrepancy and have changed it.  Actually there are few partitions which have been created in SL.  Those partitions , I am not able use through UBUNTU e.g saving a file there or copying something from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to mount the partition.

Try making sure all these packages are installed:

`sudo apt-get install fuse mount mountall mtools udisks usbmount pmount`

Also make sure you have installed 'gvfs' metapackage:

`sudo apt-get install gvfs*`

Then try rebooting.

If that doesn't work, you may have to manually mount the drives. You can find out which ones you should mount by using the disk utility application (search disk on the dash).